# React-Native sectionlist item going out of viewport

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, mobile

I'm facing an issue in a react-native app where I am having a long sectionlist with search filter, on searching item which is scrolled out of the viewport, it shows the result with the sticky groupby header but the item itself is invisbile, on scroll again the row comes down from top, I am struggling to fix this issue, tried some stuffs from the internet, but it didn't work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you please add some code and images? I can't understand what behavior you're expecting or what problem you're facing..

Comment: please add a code example.

Comment: Sample code for reference :- <SectionList
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
            sections={testData}
            refreshing={testData}
            keyExtractor={testData}
            renderItem={testData}
            renderSectionHeader={testData}
            onRefresh={testData}
            onScroll={testData}
            ListFooterComponent={testData}
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={testData}
            onEndReachedThreshold={testData}
            onEndReached={testData}
          />